# Can someone help me to solve this python challenge using while loop?

Tags: python

It is only my first time using python

I wanted to creat this output but I do not know how to do it and it very frustating to practice while loops.

This is the code the I've tried

```
x=1
while x <=5:
  y=1
  while y<=5:
     print(y,end="")
      y+=1
   print("*")
   x+=1
```

The possible output should be like this

```
* 2 3 4 5
1 * 3 4 5
1 2 * 4 5
1 2 3 * 5
1 2 3 4 *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you only want to print the * when `x` is the same as `y` so add a condition to check that.

```
x=1
while x <=5:
  y=1
  while y<=5:
    if x==y:
      print('*',end="")
    else:
      print(y,end="")
    y+=1
  print()
  x+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun

```
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, (*range(1, i), '*', *range(i+1, 6)))) for i in range(1, 6)))
* 2 3 4 5
1 * 3 4 5
1 2 * 4 5
1 2 3 * 5
1 2 3 4 *
```